# Upload iOS app to Cydia?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cydia

I've looked around for a while and nothing worked. The videos say that I should have a /build/ folder inside that project's folder, but I don't have that. How can I get that, or if there is another method to upload my app to upload to Cydia?

Comment: If you go to google and type in `How to build an app for cydia` and click on the 4th link you get this: http://thebigboss.org/hosting-repository-cydia/submit-your-app/compile-for-cydia-submission

Answer (score 0):

Cydia isn't "big servers" like the appstore. You need to host a repo or find a repo that is willing to add your deb. If you can't get a computer/known repo to host it on use repospace it allows you to make a repo your self. Add the source of the repo on myrepospace it should be (username.myrepospace.com). After install the package. Good luck.